# Exclude zero from "Random Value"

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

I want to return either a -1 or a 1 from the Random Value node. Unfortunately, I get either -1, 1 or 0! Is there a way to exclude zero from the results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do it like this:

[image]

example:

[image]